# unable to display images from a folder?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, visualization

I want to read images from a folder put them into a list and then visulize them,I used this code to do so But I've got an infinit loop af image dispalying and even the output is wrong [output_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T8Tv.png)

```py
import os 
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_path='/files'
images = []
for filename in os.listdir(image_path):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_path,filename))
    images.append(img)
    # print(len(images))
    # print('data shape:', np.array(images).shape)
    for img in images:
        data=np.array(img)
        print(data.shape)
        plt.imshow(data)
        plt.show()
```

any suggestion what's wrong?

Comment: did you mean os.sep instead of os.path?

Comment: No! all I want is  to display images that are in a folder in a given path

Comment: in which way is the output wrong? did you get an execution error?

Comment: Is your indentation correct? Do you want to have a nested `for-loop`? Try removing the second `for-loop` from the first (unindent it by one)

Comment: `plt.show` should be call once

Answer (score 2):

I removed matplotlib and cv2 because it was unnecessary and replaced it with Pillow. Also, I made sure, you don’t accidentally choose a different file other than supported image files.

```py
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_path = '<PATH>'
images = []

for filename in os.listdir(image_path):
    if filename.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.gif')):
        img = plt.imread(os.path.join(image_path, filename))
        images.append(img)

for img in images:
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: This just opens the images in the Windows `Photo` app for me, is that what OP wants? What if they are working in a notebook and want to display the images in the notebook?

Comment: In that case, they can use matplotlib, since its the only module that I know that displays images in jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

i see 2 issues in your code. one, as mentioned above, is the nested loop. if you want to load and display all images, you can either load all of them and then display them (2 loops) or load and immediately display each one(one loop - no nesting). second issue you might have noticed the colors are not as they should be. more specifically, you load the image using cv2 which loads the image in BGR format and you used plt.imshow that takes RGB image. you are missing a conversion.

```py
import os 
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

images_path='/files'
images = []
for filename in os.listdir(images_path):  # check out "glob" - much cleaner
    img_bgr = cv2.imread(os.path.join(images_path, filename))
    images.append(img_bgr)

for img_bgr in images:
    # data=np.array(img)  # not needed. cv2.imread yields np.array
    img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    plt.imshow(img_rgb)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't print out your images inside the for loop. Move the image display loop outside the loop where images are read. In your original code, you were displaying each image immediately after reading it, which caused the infinite loop of image display.
Add cv2.cvtColor(data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) to convert the BGR image  to RGB format.

Answer (score -2):

This code works for me, i just added file extension checking, so it only tries to open image files.

```
import os 
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_path=r'/files'
images = []
for filename in os.listdir(image_path):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1].lower()
    if ext not in ['jpg','jpeg','png','gif']:
        continue
    img = cv2.imread(os.sep.join(image_path,filename))
    images.append(img)
    # print(len(images))
    # print('data shape:', np.array(images).shape)
    for img in images:
        data=np.array(img)
        print(data.shape)
        plt.imshow(data)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: This shows the image list each time the loop is run, eg `[0]`, `[0,1]`, `[0,1,2]`, `[0,1,2,3]`, `[0,1,2,3,4]` which is what I assume OP means by "stuck in an infinite loop". Removing the second `for-loop` as nested should be what they want